# Convertendo Word em bits - JavaScript e WebServer CLP Siemens

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web, automatização

Estou recebendo uma variável do CLP, a qual é uma Word(16).

Porém, não estou conseguindo 'converter' esta Word em 16 bits com seus respectivos valores (true or false).

1 Word = 16 bits.

Eu recebo a word com o valor 'cheio'.

Mais detalhes:
Se trata de uma aplicação WebServer. Os arquivos (html, css, ...) ficam armazenados dentro do CLP da Siemens (s7-1200 ou s7-1500). As páginas Html com JavaScript vão ler alguns valores vindos do CLP.

Valores obtidos em testes:

```
bit8    256
bit9    512
bit10   1024
bit11   2048
bit12   4096
bit13   8192
bit14   16384
bit15   32768
bit0    1
bit1    2
bit2    4
bit3    8
bit4    16
bit5    32
bit6    64
bit7    128
```

Quando o bit1 no CLP é igual a true, ele retorna o valor inteiro 2 pelo tag da Word, e assim sucessivamente. Quando bit1 e bit2 estão ativos, ele soma os valores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema criando uma função recursiva, começando pelo maior valor e diminuindo.

As variáveis cBit-- são variáveis temporárias, as quais vou decrementando. 
As variáveis bit-- são os bits finais originários da Word(16).

Estarei otimizando melhor o script, mas segue o mesmo:

```
function convertWordToBit(word) {
    var cBit00=0;
    var cBit01=0;
    var cBit02=0;
    var cBit03=0;
    var cBit04=0;
    var cBit05=0;
    var cBit06=0;
    var cBit07=0;
    var cBit08=0;
    var cBit09=0;
    var cBit10=0;
    var cBit11=0;
    var cBit12=0;
    var cBit13=0;
    var cBit14=0;
    var cBit15=0;


    var bit00=false;
    var bit01=false;
    var bit02=false;
    var bit03=false;
    var bit04=false;
    var bit05=false;
    var bit06=false;
    var bit07=false;
    var bit08=false;
    var bit09=false;
    var bit10=false;
    var bit11=false;
    var bit12=false;
    var bit13=false;
    var bit14=false;
    var bit15=false;

    //Carrega valor da word
    cBit15=word;

    if(cBit15>=32768){
        cBit15=cBit15-32768;    
        bit15=true;
    }
    if(cBit15<32768){
        cBit14=cBit15;  
    }

    if(cBit14>=16384){
        cBit14=cBit14-16384;    
        bit14=true;
    }
    if(cBit14<16384){
        cBit13=cBit14;  
    }


    if(cBit13>=8192){
        cBit13=cBit13-8192; 
        bit13=true;
    }
    if(cBit13<8192){
        cBit12=cBit13;  
    }


    if(cBit12>=4096){
        cBit12=cBit12-4096; 
        bit12=true;
    }
    if(cBit12<4096){
        cBit11=cBit12;  
    }


    if(cBit11>=2048){
        cBit11=cBit11-2048; 
        bit11=true;
    }
    if(cBit11<2048){
        cBit10=cBit11;  
    }


    if(cBit10>=1024){
        cBit10=cBit10-1024; 
        bit10=true;
    }
    if(cBit10<1024){
        cBit09=cBit10;  
    }


    if(cBit09>=512){
        cBit09=cBit09-512;  
        bit09=true;
    }
    if(cBit09<512){
        cBit08=cBit09;  
    }


    if(cBit08>=256){
        cBit08=cBit08-256;  
        bit08=true;
    }
    if(cBit08<256){
        cBit07=cBit08;  
    }


    if(cBit07>=128){
        cBit07=cBit07-128;  
        bit07=true;
    }
    if(cBit07<128){
        cBit06=cBit07;  
    }


    if(cBit06>=64){
        cBit06=cBit06-64;   
        bit06=true;
    }
    if(cBit06<64){
        cBit05=cBit06;  
    }


    if(cBit05>=32){
        cBit05=cBit05-32;   
        bit05=true;
    }
    if(cBit05<32){
        cBit04=cBit05;  
    }


    if(cBit04>=16){
        cBit04=cBit04-16;   
        bit04=true;
    }
    if(cBit04<16){
        cBit03=cBit04;  
    }


    if(cBit03>=8){
        cBit03=cBit03-8;    
        bit03=true;
    }
    if(cBit03<8){
        cBit02=cBit03;  
    }


    if(cBit02>=4){
        cBit02=cBit02-4;    
        bit02=true;
    }
    if(cBit02<4){
        cBit01=cBit02;  
    }


    if(cBit01>=2){
        cBit01=cBit01-2;    
        bit01=true;
    }
    if(cBit01<2){
        cBit00=cBit01;  
    }


    if(cBit00>=1){
        cBit00=cBit00-1;    
        bit00=true;
    }


    //Exibindo valores
    document.getElementById('eme8').innerHTML = bit08;
    document.getElementById('eme9').innerHTML = bit09;
    document.getElementById('eme10').innerHTML = bit10;
    document.getElementById('eme11').innerHTML = bit11;
    document.getElementById('eme12').innerHTML = bit12;
    document.getElementById('eme13').innerHTML = bit13;
    document.getElementById('eme14').innerHTML = bit14;
    document.getElementById('eme15').innerHTML = bit15;

    document.getElementById('eme0').innerHTML = bit00;
    document.getElementById('eme1').innerHTML = bit01;
    document.getElementById('eme2').innerHTML = bit02;
    document.getElementById('eme3').innerHTML = bit03;
    document.getElementById('eme4').innerHTML = bit04;
    document.getElementById('eme5').innerHTML = bit05;
    document.getElementById('eme6').innerHTML = bit06;
    document.getElementById('eme7').innerHTML = bit07;



}
```